# WCF ProtectionLevel parameter: Security and reliability

Tags: c#, wcf, security, encryption

When requiring to communicate secrets between a group of clients and a server, I normally develop a customized key-exchange (over RSA) and AES encryption in which public key is requested from server to encrypt AES keys and communicate the key between receivers, so that they decrypt the encrypted bytes using (AES). However, I've known about the `ProtectionLevel` attribute in both `OperationContract` and the `MessageContract`classes, but I've been unsure about the security layer they provide for protecting the messages.

In comparison with the approach I explained, would it be secure to make use of the built in `ProtectionLevel` instead?

By security I mean, if the communicated packets are eavesdropped by a third party, which approach can better safeguard the data?

Comment: _"I normally develop a customized key-exchange [...] would it be [more] secure to make use of the built in [encryption] instead?"_ - yes, for every variation of that question.

Comment: @CodeCaster: This can be accepted if you explain how the built in security measure works and what it make use of. (Algorithm, Key Size, etc)

Comment: That's all pretty well documented, all I'm saying is that it's always better to use built-in security than to roll your own.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes exactly, I have the same idea, but I could not find much useful information about how this exactly work (not how to use it), so I decided to post the question to see if anyone knows about its internal mechanism.